# onepage_scroll.js on Ajax content causes multiple keypress events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vertical-scrolling, custom-scrolling

I am currently using the [onepage_scroll.js plugin](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)

```
main.onepage_scroll({
    loop: false,
    animationTime: 750,
    pagination: false
});
```

As well as using Ajax to pull in new content - but when the ajax request is added, the functionality for onepage_scroll is not being updated for the new content.

I tried to run the onepage_scroll plugin again on ajax success, which seems like a poor performance choice, and a bit hack-y, but it got the closest success that I was able to achieve.

```
beforeSend: function() {
    $('<span class="loading"></span>').hide().prependTo('body').fadeIn(300);
    main.addClass(removingClass);
    setTimeout(function() {
        main.empty();
    }, 750);
},
success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.loading').remove();
        main.html(data).removeClass().removeAttr('style');
        main.onepage_scroll({
            loop: false,
            animationTime: 750,
            pagination: false
        });
    }, 750);
}
```

As you can see, I had to remove the classes added (via onepage_scroll) and remove all inline styles (also onepage_scroll) before calling the plugin again.

Besides being hacky, this left the key events (up key to scroll up, down key to scroll down, space to go down, shift+space to go up) running multiple times, one additional scrolled panel per time I've called the ajax request (ie: 2 ajax requests causes one keypress to scroll 3 panels).

Is there a way to automatically add onepage_scroll functionality to the newly added ajax content, without having to call the entire plugin again? Or possibly a way to keep the original keypress functionality after ajax call?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Looks like a limitation of onepage_scroll - you'll have to initiate after every html change. I don't see any kind of refresh function for that plugin.

Comment: My issue when initiating after an HTML change was the multiple keypress issue - which I can't seem to find a way around?

Comment: Need to unbind the keypress events from the plugin when re-initialising the one page_scroll. You need to take a close look at the bind events in the plugin and unbind them all before re-initialising

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response everybody - all it took was unbinding all keydown functionality with:

> $(document).unbind('keydown');

I run that whenever I call the onepage_scroll plugin, and all is right in the world!